# how to form submit on load in react js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms

How do I submit a `form` when the page loads in ReactJS?

```
<form id="redirectForm" method="post" action="https://test.cashfree.com/billpay/checkout/post/submit">
  <input type="text" name="appId" value={this.state.appId}/>
  <input type="text" name="orderId" value={this.state.orderId}/>
  <input type="text" name="orderAmount" value={this.state.orderAmount}/>
  <input type="text" name="orderCurrency" value={this.state.orderCurrency}/>
  <input type="text" name="orderNote" value={this.state.orderNote} />
  <input type="text" name="customerName" value={this.state.customerName}/>
  <input type="text" name="customerEmail" value={this.state.customerEmail} />
  <input type="text" name="customerPhone" value={this.state.customerPhone} />
  <input type="text" name="returnUrl" value={this.state.returnUrl} />
  <input type="text" name="notifyUrl" value={this.state.notifyUrl} />
  <input type="text" name="signature" value={this.state.signature}/>
  <button type="submit">Pay</button>
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
<script>document.getElementById("redirectForm").submit();</script>
```

Comment: maybe this can help https://www.tutorialspoint.com/reactjs/reactjs_forms.htm

Comment: You can actually do the same exact thing in react inside componentDidMount for older versions or inside useEffect(with no dependencies)

Comment: @kimobrian254 share the example code document.getElementById("redirectForm").submit() like in react js

Comment: @ManjuanthVM react runs regular JS so just doing `document.getElementById("redirectForm").submit();` will work as expected. As I said inside componentDidMount for older versions on inside useEffect for newer react versions.

Comment: @kimobrian254 thank you it's working have a great day

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can actually create a ref for the form, and if the component is class component, you can use `componentDidMount` to submit the form, or if functional component, you can do it via `useEffect`

```
<form ref={item => this.form = item} id="redirectForm" method="post" action="https://test.cashfree.com/billpay/checkout/post/submit"> 
.....
</form>
```

In your React component, you can create ref using:

```
class SampleClass extends React.Component {
   constructor() {
     this.form = null
   }

   componentDidMount() {
    this.form.submit();
   }
}
```

You can apply similar logic to a function component using useRef and useEffect.

More details : https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html